# Pandas Panel fancy indexing: How to return (index of) all DataFrames in Panel based on Boolean of multiple columns in each df

Tags: python, indexing, panel, dataframe, pandas

I've got a Pandas Panel with many DataFrames with the same rows/column labels.  I want to make a new panel with DataFrames that fulfill certain criteria based on a couple columns.

This is easy with dataframes and rows:  Say I have a df, zHe_compare.  I can get the suitable rows with:

```
zHe_compare[(zHe_compare['zHe_calc'] > 100) & (zHe_compare['zHe_med'] > 100) | ((zHe_obs_lo_2s <=zHe_compare['zHe_calc']) & (zHe_compare['zHe_calc'] <= zHe_obs_hi_2s))]
```

but how do I do (pseudocode, simplified boolean):

```
good_results_panel = results_panel[ all_dataframes[ sum ('zHe_calc' < 'zHe_obs') > min_num ] ]
```

I know the the inner boolean part, but how do I specify this for each dataframe in a panel?  Because I need multiple columns from each df, I haven't met success using the `panel.minor_xs` slicing techniques.

thanks!

Comment: @ Chang She, thanks for the suggestion.  I've played around with it but can't figure out how to do the indexing correctly.  E.g. how do I specify `'zHe_calc'` from each dataframe?  I have tried `results_panel[ results_panel.ix[ sum( results_panel.ix['zHe_calc'] < zHe_obs) > min_num) ] ]` and many variations on that.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in its [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#panel), `Panel` is currently a bit under-developed, so the sweet syntax you've come to rely on when working with `DataFrame` isn't there yet.

Meanwhile, I would suggest using the `Panel.select` method:

```
def is_good_result(item_label):
    # whatever condition over the selected item
    df = results_panel[item_label]
    return df['col1'].sum() > 5

good_results = results.select(is_good_result)
```

The `is_good_result` function returns a boolean value. Note that its argument is not a `DataFrame` instance, because `Panel.select` applies its argument to the item label, rather than the `DataFrame` content of that item.

Of course, you can stuff that whole criterion function into a lambda in one statement, if you're into the whole brevity thing:

```
good_results = results.select(
                 lambda item_label: results[item_label]['col1'].sum() > 5
                 )
```